# variable as column name in where clause in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I am working on PL/SQL code where I need to perform a select query using variable as column name in where clause. Column names are stored in a table as varchar and I am using a loop to pass those column names to my select statement.

Please find sample code segment I am trying to run:

```
set serveroutput on;

declare
var varchar2(100);
counter number;
begin

var:='description';
select count(*) 
into counter
            from nodetable
           where  var like '%Ship%';

dbms_output.put_line(counter);
end;
```

Output:

```
anonymous block completed
0
```

However the result should be 86.
Oracle is comparing last condition as two string and not column=string.

Please let me know if this is even feasible in oracle or if there is a workaround for it.

Regards
Ankit

Comment: _"Column names are stored in a table as varchar"_ this is quite confusing. Are you saying that you have a table whose rows contains column names of other table ? Just like the standard [`USER_TAB_COLUMNS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4462.htm#REFRN26277). Or is it something else ?

Comment: yes, column names are stored in another table as rows just like standard user_tab_columns.

Comment: The WHERE clause in your example has nothing to do with the information in the table mentioned, that's why you get a wrong result. Each WHERE/AND clause should at some point refer the name of a column from the objects listed in the FROM clause. Well, in basic SQL that is true. More complex statements exist, but this is true for your case.

Comment: So you have a table which describes columns. Do you also have one which describes tables?

Comment: No, column datatype is not stored in that table just name of the column is present. Also, as per my requirement I only want column name to be present in where clause.
       where 'columnname' like 'something'

Answer (score 5):

You have to use dynamic SQL, preferrably with bind-variables:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
   'select count(*) from nodetable where '||var||' like :p1' 
   INTO counter 
   USING '%Ship%';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
declare
var varchar2(100);
counter number;
begin

var:='description';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'select count(*) 
into counter
            from nodetable
           where  '||var||' like ''%Ship%'' ';

dbms_output.put_line(counter);
end;
```

You need to be carefull with the colon's (').

Answer (score 0):

I agreed with previous answer in implementation, but i strictly recommend you to change your technical requirements, because you can't use bind variables for this, and it's potential place for injection. For example, if someone will edit value in your table which stores column names, to something like that: "description = inject_function or description". Then your dynamic sql block will execute this statement:

```
select count(*) from nodetable where description = inject_function or description like '%Ship%
```

and example implementation of function

```
create function inject_function
return varchar2
is pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
    delete * from most_important_table;
    commit;
    return to_char(null);
exception when others then
    rollback;
    return to_char(null);
end;
```